# Xamarin Forms NavigationPage.BarTextColor doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I read in different articles that it's working, but somehow it doesn't for me.
I added into plist

```
  <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
  <false/>
```

And

```
  var p = new FreshNavigationContainer(page);
  p.BarTextColor = Color.Fuchsia;
  p.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Aqua;
  MainPage = p;
```

FreshNavigationContainer is derived from NavigationPage.

I want to have an ability to change the status bar color on each page. When a page is dark - I need status bar to be light. And vice versa.

Comment: Hi Vorotnyak! Is this problem only happening in iOS? Can you confirm whether it is also happening on the Android app?

Comment: I've left an answer based on some guesses to what you are expecting. If you can update the question with more specifics as to what you want to change I will adjust my answer if needed.

Comment: Can you your share FreshNavigationContainer code?

Comment: @Atul This code isn't mine. Here https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Now I only care about iOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is some confusion on exactly what you are trying to change the color of.

`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` is usually used in combination with changing the status bar text color. For example,

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle (UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);
```

That would make a change like this:

[image]

It looks like you might be expecting `BarTextColor` to change this. However, that changes the text "My Expenses" in the image above.

You'll have to change the status bar text color in the iOS project using an iOS API (not Forms). Sample [here](http://motzcod.es/post/110755300272/ios-tip-change-status-bar-icon-text-colors). If you want your entire app to have a light text color in the status bar, update your info.plist to:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Update:

If you want to change the status bar color of each page, you need to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to true. Then, you would need to use a `PageRenderer` in your iOS project for each page that you want to change the status bar color for. In the renderer, you can call `UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;` in the `ViewWillAppear` method.

Keep in mind that you have limited options on the style, listed [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIStatusBarStyle/).

Comment: I want to have an ability to change status bar color on each page separately. How can I do it?
Code above changes status bar color for the whole app